# How to deal with application that always not responding?

Tags: javascript, performance

My application has developed using django framework and jQuery. After run the application for a while it always not responding or "Aw,Snap!" in Chrome within unexpected time.

The issue that I thought first is running javascript every 2 seconds with loading some values. I have a few pages that run this kind of scripts. The scripts are like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).load(function loadMap(){
        var mappos = $("#mappos").val();
        var pcode = $("#pcode").val();
        var width = $("#width").val();
        var loss = $("#loss").val();
        var lossarr = $("#lossarr").val();
        var spcode = $("#spcode").val();
        var swidth = $("#swidth").val();
        var cpcode = $('#minclamp', top.document).contents().find('#cpcode').val();
        var cwidth = $('#minclamp', top.document).contents().find('#cwidth').val();
        var lane = $('#minclamp', top.document).contents().find('#lane').val();
        var position = $('#minclamp', top.document).contents().find('#position').val();
        var atlane = $('#minclamp', top.document).contents().find('#atlane').val();
        var atposition = $('#minclamp', top.document).contents().find('#atposition').val();
        var clamping = $("#clamping").val();
        var changed = $("#changed").val();
        var realtag = $('#minclamp', top.document).contents().find('#realtag').val()
        $("#inventory").load(inventory_url+"?pcode="+pcode+"&width="+width+"&loss="+loss+"&lossarr="+lossarr+"&spcode="+spcode+"&swidth="+swidth+"&cpcode="+cpcode+"&cwidth="+cwidth+"&lane="+lane+"&position="+position+"&atlane="+atlane+"&atposition="+atposition+"&clamping="+clamping+"&changed="+changed+"&realtag="+realtag+"&mappos="+mappos);
        }

        setTimeout(loadMap, 2000);
    });
});
```

If I am right, is there any other codes that do the same but not lead to not responding event like this. Or is there any technique to improve this?

If there should be other issues to think about please suggest me. Thank you.

Comment: You should save the jQuery objects so you don't search for the elements every loop.

Comment: @Digital Plane The application has to monitor all those values because they are always changing.

Comment: What is the size of your page? Have you tried passing the values directly to javascript?

Comment: @Sukumar What do you mean by "size of my page"? Could you please give me an example of "passing the values directly to javacsript"?

Comment: Size of the page in KBs. For each of your call, jQuery needs to go through the entire DOM (roughly) and hence its performance depends on the size of the page. By passing values directly, I mean using JSON to pass the values to the variables or something as simple as "var variable = <?php echo $variable_value ?>;"

Comment: @Sukumar I'm not quite sure about the size of the page. Did you mean the size of `html` file which kelp this script, if so, it's 41.3 KBs. For using JSON, if the values are always changing, it has to send new JSON anyway, isn't it.

Comment: ~42KB isn't a lot. Perhaps its some other issue. And yes, it would need to send the new JSON data but the difference would be that you no longer query DOM upteen number of times. There might just be quite significant time difference in the two approaches.

Comment: By jQuery objects, I mean the objects returned by `$()`. You should save them so that you don't have to look through the DOM every time: `var savedObject = $("#width");` and in the loop, `var width = savedObject.val();`.

Comment: Did you mean `var savedObject = $("#width");` out the loop and `var width = savedObject.val();` in the loop? If so, it seems not to update the values.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the settimeout in the loadMap function... after all the work is finished...  and use the [$(document).ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready) function

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var loadMap = function()
    {
        var mappos = $("#mappos").val();
        var pcode = $("#pcode").val();
        var width = $("#width").val();
        var loss = $("#loss").val();
        var lossarr = $("#lossarr").val();
        var spcode = $("#spcode").val();
        var swidth = $("#swidth").val();
        var cpcode = $('#minclamp', top.document).contents().find('#cpcode').val();
        var cwidth = $('#minclamp', top.document).contents().find('#cwidth').val();
        var lane = $('#minclamp', top.document).contents().find('#lane').val();
        var position = $('#minclamp', top.document).contents().find('#position').val();
        var atlane = $('#minclamp', top.document).contents().find('#atlane').val();
        var atposition = $('#minclamp',  top.document).contents().find('#atposition').val();
        var clamping = $("#clamping").val();
        var changed = $("#changed").val();
        var realtag = $('#minclamp', top.document).contents().find('#realtag').val()
        $("#inventory").load(inventory_url+"?pcode="+pcode+"&width="+width+"&loss="+loss+"&lossarr="+lossarr+"&spcode="+spcode+"&swidth="+swidth+"&cpcode="+cpcode+"&cwidth="+cwidth+"&lane="+lane+"&position="+position+"&atlane="+atlane+"&atposition="+atposition+"&clamping="+clamping+"&changed="+changed+"&realtag="+realtag+"&mappos="+mappos, function()
        {
           // set the timer here in the completeCallback of your 'load' function.
             setTimeout(function()                  
             {
                loadMap();
             }, 2000);
        }));           
    }; 
    loadMap();// call the first load map;
});
```

Comment: Actually I also used `$(document).ready` function but I just put only related lines in my question, so sorry and I have already edited it. Anyway after tried your solution, it seems to make some contents blink and doesn't make it faster.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using separate threads?

EDIT:
if you know what you are looking for: http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/10/
Very nice

Comment: This looks promising: http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/000315.html                       I have successfully removed unresponsive screens in C# by using threads, I hope it's similar with JavaScript

Comment: Ufortunately, it's not. Threads are not supported in most browsers. The link you posted only works with firefox, and Web Workers (sort of like threads) is also not cross-browser compliant.

Comment: Well, then I am sorry, but I can assist no further. I have never really developed with JavaScript, just played with it. Good luck. Regards